# fullcalendar is not working on Mozilla and Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My fullcalendar is not working on internet explorer and mozilla. It works on chrome perfectly well but not on IE and Moz. It will display the calendar, but would not display the events, and this is the jquery file that gets the events and displays them.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {

        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    events: "assets/php/json-events.php",

    editable: true,

    eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
        alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
            '(should probably update your database)');
    },

    loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            $('#loading').show();
        } else {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you posted php; if the calendar works in chrome then what we need to see is the output. Can you provide a link, or a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the same problem?

Comment: I agree with @sinetheta, If it is functioning in the other browsers than it is not a server issue, it is a client issue. We need to see client code. Show us the JS

Comment: This is ð site http://www.gicfamily.org/events . U̶̲̥̅̊ are right, I used mozilla's firebug to see if ð info was retrieved and ð info was there on firebug but was not displaying on ð calendar, what do U̶̲̥̅̊ think could be ð issue?

Comment: You need to post the actual js code into jsfiddle or here on stack overflow so we can see it in a concise manner, otherwise NO one will help you!

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix this error. My solution was simple: all months and dates less than or equal to 9 should have the 0 prefix before the number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include the working solution?

Comment: No need for providing a working solution. It is self explanatory if you are a developer.